# How to return value from loop. js, vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Sorry, I'm beginner with JS,i have a basic question, but i spent a whole day trying to find answer in google and i didn't.

I have a massic financial instrument developed on php and I need to build complex financial calculator that shows everything with reactivity. I need help to figure out how to make complex calculations with many `if` statements inside of the loop and then sum output value from each object in array and return total summed value. Using Vuejs for this.

So my `cashDividends()` must be a sum of calculated values from each object in the loop.

Below I put a piece of code to understand problem I'm facing.

Please check if have a minute. Thanks!

```
     new Vue({
    el: "#waterfall",
    data() {
        return {
        info: {
            cash_dividends: true,
            converted_liabilities: true,
        },
        equities: [
            @foreach($preferredEquities as $equity)
            { name: '{{ $equity->name }}', id: {{ $equity->id }} },
            @endforeach
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        remainingExit () {
            return this.form.exit_value - this.form.uncovered_debt - this.form.transaction_fees
        },
        cashDividends() {
    //I supposed should be something like this.     
          this.equities.forEach(function(equity)
          {
            //Here I make a lot of calculations with bunch of if statements using object and DOM input values. for each object 

          }
          // And here I need to return sum of calculated values from each object (equity) in array 
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a variable sum and iteratively add `equity.price` to it as follows:

```
    cashDividends() {
        let sum = 0
        this.equities.forEach(function(equity)) {
            sum+=equity.price
        }

        return sum
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reduce` function which you could learn more about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    equities: [{
        name: "Serias A",
        price: 20
      },
      {
        name: "Serias B",
        price: 21
      },
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    cashDividends() {
      return this.equities.reduce(this.sum);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sum(total, num) {

      return total.price + num.price
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{cashDividends}}
</div>
```

Comment: returns [object Object][object Object]

Comment: and idea to loop it, because I need to make crazy math calculations inside of loop to get the value before sum it.

Comment: @PhilippNoris, sorry i did a typo, i fixed it

Comment: you could make that math calculations inside `sum` method or you could rename to be me accurate

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'm going to try it. Thx!

Comment: you're welcome, the array functions like `map`,`reduce` and `filter` .., they make the things to be easier

Comment: the mothod works if I only have 2 objects in array. How it should work if many? Could you please show what I need to learn to understand this part. I need to make massive calculations for each object in array and than sum of outputs for every array object

Comment: you could edit your question by adding that details and i will be here to help you

Comment: like i said before you could do any calculation inside `sum` method

Answer (score 1):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function

```
new Vue({
el: "#waterfall",
data: {
    equities: [
           {name: "Serias A", price: '20'},
           {name: "Serias B", price: '21'},
        ]
},
computed: {
    cashDividends() {
        var sum = this.equities.reduce(function(acc, equity) {
            return acc + parseInt(equity.price);
        }, 0)
    }
}
});
```