# Calculations inside of loop and how to return sum of values . Vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm very beginner to javascript and need to navigate me on the right way how to use it in my task.

I have a massive financial instrument developed on php and I need to build complex financial calculator that shows everything with reactivity. I need help to figure out how to make complex calculations with many `if` statements inside of the loop and then sum output value from each object in array and return total summed value. Using Vuejs for this.

So my `cashDividends()` must be a sum of calculated values from each object in the loop.

Below I put a piece of code to understand problem I'm facing.

```
 new Vue({
    el: "#waterfall",
    data() {
        return {
        info: {
            cash_dividends: true,
            converted_liabilities: true,
        },
        equities: [
            @foreach($preferredEquities as $equity)
            { name: '{{ $equity->name }}', id: {{ $equity->id }} },
            @endforeach
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        remainingExit () {
            return this.form.exit_value - this.form.uncovered_debt - this.form.transaction_fees
        },
        cashDividends() {
    //I supposed should be something like this.     
          this.equities.forEach(function(equity)
          {
            //Here I make a lot of calculations with bunch of if statements using object and DOM input values. for each object 

          }
          // And here I need to return sum of calculated values from each object (equity) in array 
        }
    },
```

Any tips guys, just need to figure out the concept.

Comment: Forget about Vue. Do it in plain old JavaScript. Create a function that takes in your data and  output s the sum. 
Once your calculations correct. Then use Vue to display the results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from loop. js, vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53843038/how-to-return-value-from-loop-js-vuejs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it sounds like you should use a `reduce`

```
const total = this.equities.reduce((sum, equity) => {
  const myEquityCalc = << something >>;
  return sum + myEquityCalc;
}, 0)
```

**Demo:**

```js
const equities = [{value: 100}, {value: 200}];

const total = equities.reduce((sum, equity) => {
  return sum + equity.value;
}, 0)

console.log(total)
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the respond, I'm going to make a test with it.

Comment: have undefined output

Comment: might be an issue in your calculations - I added a demo to help